# SQL server agent Jobs step

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-s3, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I'm trying to setup new job step in SQL Server Agent.
I need to do with `powershell` with administrator. What I am trying is:

```
$env:Path += ';C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI'
aws s3 sync D:\MSSQLBackups\ s3://myfolder/DB_backups
```

If I do it from `powershell` it works well.
But, if I create job step with `powershell type` or `cmd`, it does not work.
Where is my mistake?

Comment: This might be better on the dba.stackexchange.com sister site

Comment: Problem fixed. As i understood Job step launch from user SQLSERVERAGENT. So, i just copied folder .aws from C:\Users\Administrator to C:\Users\SQLSERVERAGENT (but before i have setup aws configure. In .aws folder you should have 2 files: config, credentilas).

Answer (score 1):

Problem fixed. As i understood Job step launch from user SQLSERVERAGENT. So, i just copied folder .aws from C:\Users\Administrator to C:\Users\SQLSERVERAGENT (but before i have setup aws configure. In .aws folder you should have 2 files: config, credentilas).